# What's the difference between "coalesce" and "cohesive"?

Tags: differences

I can't find the answer anywhere.

As I understand, "cohesive" is something like a blockchain and "coalesce" is something like the USA. Am I correct?

Please help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: First off, "coalesce" is a verb and "cohesive" is an adjective (whose related verb is "cohere").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both conveys a similar  meaning, but the former is a verb while the latter is an adjective. The idea is that different parts may coalesce together  to form a cohesive unit.

> ***[Coalesce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/coalesce-2008-04-02)*** unites the prefix co- ("together") and the Latin verb alescere, meaning "to grow." (The words adolescent and adult also grew from alescere.) Coalesce, which first appeared in English in the mid-16th century, is one of a number of verbs in English (along with mix, commingle, merge, and amalgamate) that *refer to the act of combining parts into a whole. In particular, coalesce usually implies the merging of similar parts to form a cohesive unit.* (M-W)

while

> The adjective ***[cohesive](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cohesive)*** comes from the Latin word cohaerere, or “to cleave together.” Cohesive things stick together, so they are unified. *A cohesive neighborhood's members get together to plan things like block parties, and they work together to solve problems. A cohesive fitness plan would include menus and exercise routines designed to lose weight, build muscle, and so on.* (Vocabulary.com)

Comment: So something becomes cohesive by coalescing.